# Scala not working with heroku example

Tags: scala, heroku

I'm following a tutorial to create a scala web app with Heroku here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scala

I've copied there example exactly, but when I run

```
sbt clean compile stage
```

It fails to compile because of these errors:

```
[error] /home/ajcrites/dev/dyl/src/main/scala/Web.scala:1: object jboss is not a member of package org
[error] import org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.{HttpRequest, HttpResponse}
[error]            ^
[error] /home/ajcrites/dev/dyl/src/main/scala/Web.scala:2: object twitter is not a member of package com
[error] import com.twitter.finagle.builder.ServerBuilder
[error]            ^
[error] /home/ajcrites/dev/dyl/src/main/scala/Web.scala:3: object twitter is not a member of package com
[error] import com.twitter.finagle.http.{Http, Response}
[error]            ^
[error] /home/ajcrites/dev/dyl/src/main/scala/Web.scala:4: object twitter is not a member of package com
[error] import com.twitter.finagle.Service
[error]            ^
[error] /home/ajcrites/dev/dyl/src/main/scala/Web.scala:5: object twitter is not a member of package com
[error] import com.twitter.util.Future
[error]            ^
[error] 5 errors found
```

Basically, I think it has to do with finagle not being available or not in the packages I have or something.  However, I have no idea how to install finagle and there are neither instructions in the tutorial above nor at https://github.com/twitter/finagle

What can I do to get this to compile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If will depend on the version of Scala and Finagle you want to use, but to add Finagle to the project, just add the following to build.sbt

```
libraryDependencies += "com.twitter" % "finagle-core_2.9.1" % "1.11.0" exclude("org.apache.thrift", "libthrift")

libraryDependencies += "com.twitter" % "finagle-http_2.9.1" % "1.11.0"

libraryDependencies += "com.twitter" % "finagle-serversets_2.9.1" % "1.11.0" excludeAll(
  ExclusionRule(organization = "com.sun.jdmk"),
  ExclusionRule(organization = "com.sun.jmx"),
  ExclusionRule(organization = "javax.jms")
)
```

This example is about 3 months old, so I'm sure you can get a newer version of Finagle.

Comment: If people are experiencing this issue using the 'Make Project' button in IDEA, try using 'sbt clean compile stage' command instead.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the code and it worked for me.  Perhaps see if the source on GitHub works:  https://github.com/heroku/devcenter-scala

Comment: James, since you are the right guy to ask. Will you be releasing a similar tutorial on other popular Scala service libraries, such as Spray? And other persistence models, such as SLICK (ScalaQuery)? I realize you can't do everything ;-) Just curious.

Comment: I would like to create more Scala tutorials.  Should Spray and SLICK be my top priorities?

Comment: Both Spray and SLICK are very new, but very exiting and well designed. Unless I'm wrong, and I'm never wrong (from The Princess Bride ;-), they are both going to become very popular for light weight REST service stacks. Nice video intro to Spray: http://marakana.com/s/spray_rest_on_akka_from_the_northeast_scala_symposium,1150/index.html